# how can i find the names and RGB values of colors in a .net Palette

Tags: .net, vb.net, user-interface, charts, rgb

I've got a chart showing data as a part of a vb.net forms application. The Chart object makes a really pretty picture, but I need it to match the color scheme on the rest of the UI. How do I get the RGB values for the palette?

```
Debug.Print(Chart1.Palette.Chocolate.WHAT ARE THE RGB COLORS??!)
```

**Edit 1**

Note: Chocolate is both the name of a color and the name of a .net Palette   The post above refers to Chocolate the Palette, which contains multiple colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The struct `System.Drawing.Color` has static properties with webcolors:

```
Color c = System.Drawing.Color.Chocolate;
int r = c.R;
int g = c.G;
int b = c.B;
```

---

This will return color names:

```
foreach (string colorName in Enum.GetNames(typeof(System.Drawing.KnownColor))) {
    Console.WriteLine(colorName);
}
```

The `ToString()` method of `System.Drawing.Color` will return a color name if the color is a known color, otherwise  A, R, G, B values:

```
System.Drawing.Color.Chocolate.ToString()  --> "Color [Chocolate]"
System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(254).ToString()  --> "Color [A=0, R=0, G=0, B=254]"
```

---

A palette is a selected set of colors. This is a palette:

[image]

This is another palette:

[image]

---

Finally I found the answer by using .NET Reflector:
In the `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Utilities` namespace there is an internal static class `ChartPaletteColors`. Since it is internal you can't access it. But reflector shows how the color palettes are initialized. Form this I got the following palettes:

```
Berry = { BlueViolet, MediumOrchid, RoyalBlue, MediumVioletRed, Blue, BlueViolet, Orchid, MediumSlateBlue, ARGB(0xc0, 0, 0xc0), MediumBlue, Purple }
BrightPastel = { ARGB(0x41, 140, 240), ARGB(0xfc, 180, 0x41), ARGB(0xe0, 0x40, 10), ARGB(5, 100, 0x92), ARGB(0xbf, 0xbf, 0xbf), ARGB(0x1a, 0x3b, 0x69), ARGB(0xff, 0xe3, 130), ARGB(0x12, 0x9c, 0xdd), ARGB(0xca, 0x6b, 0x4b), ARGB(0, 0x5c, 0xdb), ARGB(0xf3, 210, 0x88), ARGB(80, 0x63, 0x81), ARGB(0xf1, 0xb9, 0xa8), ARGB(0xe0, 0x83, 10), ARGB(120, 0x93, 190) }
Chocolate = { Sienna, Chocolate, DarkRed, Peru, Brown, SandyBrown, SaddleBrown, ARGB(0xc0, 0x40, 0), Firebrick, ARGB(0xb6, 0x5c, 0x3a) }
Default = { Green, Blue, Purple, Lime, Fuchsia, Teal, Yellow, Gray, Aqua, Navy, Maroon, Red, Olive, Silver, Tomato, Moccasin }
Earth = { ARGB(0xff, 0x80, 0), DarkGoldenrod, ARGB(0xc0, 0x40, 0), OliveDrab, Peru, ARGB(0xc0, 0xc0, 0), ForestGreen, Chocolate, Olive, LightSeaGreen, SandyBrown, ARGB(0, 0xc0, 0), DarkSeaGreen, Firebrick, SaddleBrown, ARGB(0xc0, 0, 0) }
Excel = { ARGB(0x99, 0x99, 0xff), ARGB(0x99, 0x33, 0x66), ARGB(0xff, 0xff, 0xcc), ARGB(0xcc, 0xff, 0xff), ARGB(0x66, 0, 0x66), ARGB(0xff, 0x80, 0x80), ARGB(0, 0x66, 0xcc), ARGB(0xcc, 0xcc, 0xff), ARGB(0, 0, 0x80), ARGB(0xff, 0, 0xff), ARGB(0xff, 0xff, 0), ARGB(0, 0xff, 0xff), ARGB(0x80, 0, 0x80), ARGB(0x80, 0, 0), ARGB(0, 0x80, 0x80), ARGB(0, 0, 0xff) }
Fire = { Gold, Red, DeepPink, Crimson, DarkOrange, Magenta, Yellow, OrangeRed, MediumVioletRed, ARGB(0xdd, 0xe2, 0x21) }
Light = { Lavender, LavenderBlush, PeachPuff, LemonChiffon, MistyRose, Honeydew, AliceBlue, WhiteSmoke, AntiqueWhite, LightCyan }
Pastel = { SkyBlue, LimeGreen, MediumOrchid, LightCoral, SteelBlue, YellowGreen, Turquoise, HotPink, Khaki, Tan, DarkSeaGreen, CornflowerBlue, Plum, CadetBlue, PeachPuff, LightSalmon }
SeaGreen = { SeaGreen, MediumAquamarine, SteelBlue, DarkCyan, CadetBlue, MediumSeaGreen, MediumTurquoise, LightSteelBlue, DarkSeaGreen, SkyBlue }
SemiTransparent = { ARGB(150, 0xff, 0, 0), ARGB(150, 0, 0xff, 0), ARGB(150, 0, 0, 0xff), ARGB(150, 0xff, 0xff, 0), ARGB(150, 0, 0xff, 0xff), ARGB(150, 0xff, 0, 0xff), ARGB(150, 170, 120, 20), ARGB(80, 0xff, 0, 0), ARGB(80, 0, 0xff, 0), ARGB(80, 0, 0, 0xff), ARGB(80, 0xff, 0xff, 0), ARGB(80, 0, 0xff, 0xff), ARGB(80, 0xff, 0, 0xff), ARGB(80, 170, 120, 20), ARGB(150, 100, 120, 50), ARGB(150, 40, 90, 150) }
```

The GrayScale palette is determined by:
`gray value = 200 - (i * 11)`
where `i` ranges from 0 to 15.

Comment: Thanks Olivier. So how do I print out all of the colors in a palette?

Comment: If you are talking about the ChartColorPalette, there seems to be no way to iterate through the colors. However the article [Setting Microsoft Chart Series Colors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/10/06/setting-chart-series-colors.aspx) shows a picture of the colors of the different chart palettes.

Comment: I added a final answer (EDIT #3) which shows the colors used in the chart palettes.

Answer (score 1):

`Chocolate` is within the `System.Drawing.KnownColor` enumeration.  Hence you can do the following to get it's ARGB values, e.g.

```
Dim c As Color = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Chocolate)
Byte a = c.A
Byte r = c.R
Byte g = c.G
Byte b = c.B
```

Or simply,

```
Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Chocolate).A ...
```

Comment: unfortunately chocolate is a palette of a few colors. I guess my question can be rephrased as how do i spell out the colors in a palette?

Comment: Thanks, George. I used that method to print RGBs that match the color shown on my screen. But I'm a little confused between a color and a palette. It seems like a palette has many colors: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chartcolorpalette.aspx

Comment: A palette is a selected set of colors.

Comment: @akh2103 I think you're getting confused by the fact that there is an RGB predefined color named "Chocolate" and there is also a color palette named "Chocolate". They are not the same thing. Instead of Chocolate, consider the "EarthTones" color palette. There is no color named "EarthTones". Somewhere in the system, there is a list of RGB color values that is associated with the "EarthTones" palette. It sounds like you want to list all the RGB colors associated with a color palette.